# xlwings: how to sort excel table with headers?

Tags: python, excel, sorting, xlwings

I have an excel table that I would like to sort with XlWings. The table has a header row. I tried sorting like this:

```
wb = xw.Book(file)
ws = wb.sheets[sheet]
ws.range(table).api.Sort(ws.range(table).api,SortOrder.xlAscending,)
```

But that sorts the table such that data replaces the headers, and the header row ends up at the bottom of the table.

The following produce the same results:

```
#Setting the range to include only the table data    
ws.range("Table1[#Data]").api.Sort(ws.range("Table1[#Data]").api,SortOrder.xlAscending)

#Specifying the range has a header 
ws.range(table).api.Sort(Key1=ws.range(table).api,Order1=1,Header="xlYes")

#manually excluding the header row from the range
ws.range('c4:n380').api.Sort(ws.range('c4:n380').api,SortOrder.xlAscending)
```

I'm at my wits end. The final table will be very large, so I'd rather not write the whole thing into a dataframe, sorting it there and re-writing it to excel.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation on this topic is sketchy.

After 2 days of trying and searching, this seemed to work:

```py
last_row = ws.range(1,1).end('down').row

first_col_range = ws.range("A2:A{row}".format(row=last_row))

data_range = ws.range("A2:N{row}".format(row=last_row))

ws.range(data_range).api.Sort(Key1=first_col_range.api, Order1=1, Header=2, Orientation=1)
```

I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort to be of some help.

The solution I'm posting here refers to the example at:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-excel-xlwings-tutorial/

(xlwings Tutorial: Make Excel Faster Using Python)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue using these one-liners. The header row kept being sorted and moved to the last row. Here is how I solved it in Python (using VBA ListObjects).

```
table1 = ws.api.ListObjects("Table1")
sort_range= ws.range("Table1[#Data]").api
table1.Sort.SortFields.Add(Key=sort_range)
table1.Sort.Apply()
```